# php quotation mark is not working

Tags: php

I am facing some problem in PHP code. It is a basic question but I don't know the answer. The code is here:

```
echo '<a href="profile.php?act=show&id=<?=$_SESSION['id']?>&line=true" class="myac">My Data</a>';
```

How to use the quotation mark in the `id`? Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's wrong. Already you are using `echo`. So concatenate the value this way:

```
<?php
  echo '<a href="profile.php?act=show&id=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '&line=true" class="myac">My Data</a>';
  //-------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

And please refrain from using short tags (`<? ?>`), use full tags: `<?php ?>`.

Comment: he is using the variable `$_SESSION['id']` not just `$id`.

Comment: @low_rents Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

apart from the above mentioned way by @praveen  u can use it like below also if u don't want to put the anchor tag inside php

```
 <a href="profile.php?act=show&id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']?>&line=true" class="myac">My Data</a>
```